# replace blob with random string

Tags: database, oracle, blob

I am using Oracle 11g. One of my tables has a column of type blob. I am trying to replace the value in this column with a random string of same length as the existing value in the column. This is what I have done:

```
`update order set info = XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT XMLTYPE('<edit>'||DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', length(info))||'</edit>') as blob) where info is not null;`
```

As one of the rows has a value of length 190,000 I ran into an error saying

> String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why are you storing text data as BLOB and not CLOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maximum length of a VARCHAR2 in SQL is 4000 bytes in Oracle 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835). Any row you attempt to run this statement against that has more than 3987 bytes (4000 minus 13 for the `<edit></edit>` tags) will result in an error as you will exceed the 4000 byte limit.

You can either:

- Cap the length to 3987 like:
  `DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', GREATEST(length(info), 3987))`
- Or use PL/SQL and the [dbms_lob](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i1016465) package to build up the desired blob. PL/SQL has a maximum VARCHAR2 length of 32767 bytes but also allows for looping constructs that would allow you to loop over the `length(info)` in 32767 chunks and appending data to a lob variable using `dbms_lob.append`.

**edit:** Use GREATEST rather than MAX.

Comment: thanks for the reply mleonard, when I use `DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', MAX(length(info), 3987))` I got an error saying **group function is not allowed here**

Comment: Apologies I meant GREATEST rather than MAX. I've edited my answer, check the code there.